# How to create a stacked bar graph from nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

How can i create stacked bar graph from a dictionary like this

```
{'Chesterville': {'Bachelor': 8, 'Diploma': 5, 'Fail (Promoted)': 5, 'HC': 16},
 'Ebony Park': {'Bachelor': 1, 'Diploma': 3, 'Fail (Promoted)': 0, 'HC': 1},
 'Makhaza': {'Bachelor': 15, 'Diploma': 9, 'Fail (Promoted)': 13, 'HC': 4}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use pandas to convert the dictionary to a DataFrame and then plot it.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dic = {'Chesterville': {'Bachelor': 8, 'Diploma': 5, 'Fail (Promoted)': 5, 'HC': 16},
     'Ebony Park': {'Bachelor': 1, 'Diploma': 3, 'Fail (Promoted)': 0, 'HC': 1},
     'Makhaza': {'Bachelor': 15, 'Diploma': 9, 'Fail (Promoted)': 13, 'HC': 4}}

df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

df.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, How i can represent in other way around for this set of data. Means Chesterville, Ebony Park and Makhaza in x-axis and all the degrees data in stacked format.